# GPS location and altitude of user on a PWA application

Tags: javascript, api, progressive-web-apps

I know we are able to prompt the user to track their GPS location through the browser. However, I am trying to handle multiple floors in a building. How would one be able to collect the altitude for a GPS location. As of right now, I am only able to track the Latitude and Longitude?

Comment: Man, this is reaching back into some old old stuff I think I remember from a long time ago.  As far as I am aware, the ability to determine the altitude of a user is not very possible or accurate.  IIRC it is related to the sparse number of towers in most areas.  But I could be completely wrong about that.

Comment: @Taplar that is correct. There are very few systems set up to track altitude, and it's not possible with the built-in geolocation options in Javascript

Comment: Even with latitude and longitude, you’re not necessarily guaranteed to get an accuracy of smaller than 10 meters or so. Even if you could get altitudes, the accuracy would typically not be enough to determine a particular floor (typically ~3m).

Comment: @SampsonCrowley consider posting your comment as an answer.

Comment: Keeping in mind that as time goes on, if the ability to do this becomes more available and accurate, systems involving things like 911 calls will greatly benefit from it.

Comment: @SampsonCrowley ty! I am curious if there are other languages or systems that can work with PWAs that might allow this to happen.

Comment: @adarian if there are, they would require specialized equipment, and most likely some sort of browser extension in order to be able to access it from a website. What you are going for would currently be more suited to a native app (if the equipment even exists).

Comment: The sort of accuracy required isn't available to GPS. You'd need something like [Differential GPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_GPS), commonly installed at airports to support automated landing of aircrafts. That's not generally available. However, there are [Indoor positioning system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indoor_positioning_system)s that attempt to make up for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The geolocation position data does contain the properties `coords.altitude` and `coords.altitudeAccuracy`. At least it does in iOS.

I just ran this in the Web Inspector console on an iPhone with Safari (iOS 14.3):

```js
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos) => console.log(pos))
```

The result:

```
GeolocationPosition
  coords: GeolocationCoordinates
    accuracy: 13.6...
    altitude: 5.68...
    altitudeAccuracy: 23.7...
    floorLevel: null
    heading: null
    latitude: 37.42...
    longitude: -122.1...
    speed: 0
    timestamp: 1609...
```

The `altitudeAccuracy` value is poor, which makes sense for a GPS measurement. Altitude is always inaccurate when using GPS.

Here is the [MDN page on GeolocationCoordinates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GeolocationCoordinates), which does list both properties `altitude` and `altitudeAccuracy`.

There's also an interesting wiki page on [Indoor positioning systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indoor_positioning_system). They use several non-GPS techniques to detect which floor a device is on.

Comment: Yes this has been there for over 10 years now. However the altitude availability and accuracy varies by device and what location service is being used. I think satellite is more accurate. I built an app for a corp back in 2012 and they wanted floor accuracy. It was rough.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to get altitude from the built-in Geolocation options for JavaScript.

CORRECTION: apparently an `altitude` and `altitudeAccuracy` property has been added to the `GeolocationCoordinates` class; though I would not get my hopes up to not only to get anything usably accurate, but to even get anything besides `null` for most devices

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GeolocationCoordinates

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API

Comment: Are you sure of that? The [MDN GeolocationCoordinates page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GeolocationCoordinates) lists the properties `altitude` and `altitudeAccuracy`.

Comment: @terrymorse well color me surprised, those properties did not exist last time I was looking for this exact info for a theoretical automated food delivery service I wanted to build for the fun of it. I still would not expect anything remotely accurate in the near future; maybe when mmwave 5g is done being rolled out it will be capable of tracking altitude more accurately than current towers